# How to fix GRUB default booting Windows XP instead of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-xp, default

I've been reading a lot the last 2 weeks, but never found a working solution for my dual boot system.

Tried boot manager, this solves the automatic time setting.
Tried editing grub cfg by hand, nothing.

All i want is:

---

[ ] 1 Ubuntu

[ ] 2 Ubuntu single user

[ ] 3 Memtest

[x] 4 Windows XP

---

GRUB should boot entry 4 by default, but neither specifying the number nor the full boot entry does the job.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Use your Live CD and boot from it. Next download this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

This is what you are going to get:
[image]
Follow the instructions here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

You should try StartUp Manager. It's easy to use GUI tool. Read more: [StartUp Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StartUpManager)

Comment: erm, sorry, didn't mean boot manager, i already tried startup manager :-)

Comment: Oh I remembered that StartUp Manager didn't work on my system, so I try [Grub Customizer](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/grub-customizer-20-can-change-default.html) Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 0):

What problem exactly did you face editing grub.cfg by hand? Try changing the value in "set default="0"". Try changing the value from 0 to 3(or a greater number if you have updated your kernel". Save the file(its readonly, so you might have to change the permissions first). I faced a similar problem as well and this method worked. Cheers!